# How to deploy rabbitmq in a container with AWS ECS with persistent messages

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs

I am looking for a solution to deploy rabbitmq with AWS ECS so that messages are not lost when container is removed and new container is started.

I think this is possible if I use a cluster of one instance cause it will be forced to always use that instance and I can just mount the volume to persist data.

But at the moment I am running a cluster of multiple instances. So when ECS decides to start the container on different instance all the messages are lost.

A possible solution could be to tag one of the instances in a cluster with a tag like "purpose:rabbitmq" and use the constraint to only start tasks for this service on this instance. But I couldn't find a way to implement that with Cluster Query Language.

Comment: Do not SQS or SNS solve your problem?